# When I need to make Firefox and brave run as root and transfare Xauthority this error appear

Tags: command-line, root, firefox, error-handling

When I tried to run this command line

> `cp -a /home/root1/.Xauthority .Xauthority`

`
this error appear, What the reason is?

> `cp: cannot stat '/home/root1/.Xauthority': No such file or directory`

**please, I need help for this problem.**

Comment: You appear to be running Kali for anything other than pentesting, please don't. You won't have to run Firefox as root on a normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work for **Brave** on my Linux Mint 20.1 system:

```
xhost SI:localuser:root    # give root access to the display.
sudo su -                  # switch to root user's shell
env DISPLAY=:0.0 brave-browser --no-sandbox
```

I did not need to copy the `.Xauthority` file.

Comment: when I use third command this error appear. [2496:2496:0624/111911.487702:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1402)] Unable to open X display.

Comment: Hmmm...what does `xhost` return?

Comment: localuser:root being added to access control list

Comment: sorry about late I have final in last days sorry again.

Comment: I've tried this on (3) different systems and all work. Can you test this solution on another system? Your error(s) may be specific to Kali.